# How to determine length of day time and length of night time in a time range?

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have two dates with time in YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss format.

I have a time range in 24H standard. From 5:30 to 21:00 is day and from 21:00 to 5:30 is night.

I must check how much time (in seconds) in this period was night and how much was day.

Here is an example.

I have two dates which create a period:

date1 = 2016-08-08 12:31:35 (start)

date2 = 2016-08-09 00:29:11 (end)

From 12:31:35 to 21:00 is 34105s and from 21:00:00 to 0:29:11 is 12551s.

So, in my period I have 34105s during the day and 12551s during the night.

How can I solve when I have e.g. from 2016-08-08 12:31:35 to 2016-08-10 12:31:35 when I have two days in my period?

Answer (score 0):

VBA stores Date types as floating point numbers with the time to the right of the decimal and the date to the left.  You can get the time component by taking only the decimal part:

```
time = someDate - Int(someDate)
```

So, you can define some useful constants to use in calculating how to split the time portion into days and nights:

```
Const ONE_SECOND = 1 / 24 / 60 / 60
Const DAY_START = ONE_SECOND * 60 * 60 * 5.5
Const DAY_END = ONE_SECOND * 60 * 60 * 21
Const MIDNIGHT = 1
Const SECONDS_IN_DAY = DAY_END - DAY_START
```

Then make a simple helper function to convert a Double to a total number of seconds:

```
Public Function TotalSeconds(inValue As Double)
    TotalSeconds = Int(inValue) * 24 * 60 * 60 + _
                   Hour(inValue) * 60 * 60 + _
                   Minute(inValue) * 60 + _
                   Second(inValue)
End Function
```

Then it's just a matter of determining if the days are the same and doing some simple math on the Double portion based on whether the start and end are on the same day:

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim starting As Date, ending As Date
    starting = CDate("2016-08-08 12:31:35")
    ending = CDate("2016-08-09 00:29:11")

    Dim days As Long
    'Calculate number of days between dates.
    days = Int(ending) - Int(starting)
    'Remove the date portions
    starting = starting - Int(starting)
    ending = ending - Int(ending)

    Dim day As Double, night As Double
    If days = 0 Then  'Same day?
        day = SECONDS_IN_DAY
        If starting < DAY_START Then
            night = night + DAY_START - starting
        Else
            day = day - (starting - DAY_START)
        End If
        If ending > DAY_END Then
            night = night + (ending - DAY_END)
        Else
            day = day - (DAY_END - ending)
        End If
    Else
        'seconds from the first day.
        If starting > DAY_END Then
            night = MIDNIGHT - starting
        Else
            night = MIDNIGHT - DAY_END
            If starting > DAY_START Then
                day = DAY_END - starting
            Else
                day = SECONDS_IN_DAY
                night = night + (DAY_START - starting)
            End If
        End If
        'seconds from the last day.
        If ending > DAY_END Then
            night = night + (ending - SECONDS_IN_DAY)
            day = day + SECONDS_IN_DAY
        Else
            If ending < DAY_START Then
                night = night + ending
            Else
                night = night + DAY_START
                day = day + (ending - DAY_START)
            End If
        End If
        'seconds from full days in between
        If days > 1 Then
            night = night + ((days - 1) * (1 - SECONDS_IN_DAY))
            day = day + ((days - 1) * SECONDS_IN_DAY)
        End If
    End If

    Debug.Print "Day: " & TotalSeconds(day), "Night: " & TotalSeconds(night)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I have used different solution.
I had to have 3 forms enabled for specific times during the day and one of the forms would be from 11pm to 7am.

My solution (example):

```
If Not (DateAdd("h", 8, TimeValue(Now)) > DateAdd("h", 8, Sheets(1).Range("B25").Value) And DateAdd("h", 8, TimeValue(Now)) < DateAdd("h", 8, Sheets(1).Range("B25").Value)) Then
```

Basically I was making all calculations based on cell values by adding 8 hours to them so I would actually avoid working over midnight hours.

```
DateAdd("h", 8, TimeValue(Now))
```

This should help in some cases keeping code very simple and short.
Help reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function