# Microsoft Excel - Split Time into Day & Night

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I could really use your help!

A night shift for me begins at 1930 till 2230.

I already have a formula which tells me how long my shift is, but I am looking for a formula to split the time into Day & Night.

For Example:

I had work from 1800 till 2359. or I had work from 0300 till 0700. 
I already have a formula which tells me that I have worked for 0559 and 0400 Hours. But I am unable to get it to split into how much of it is Day and how much of it is Night.

I have been scrolling the web, but no luck!

hoping someone can help me out.

Thanks,
Jagdeep

Comment: Can you [edit] your question the formula you already have, some sample data, and the expected result?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146591/excel-vba-how-to-compare-period-time-to-time-range

Comment: "work from 1800 till 2359" > 1800 to 1930 is day, 1930 to 2230 is night, do  you want to include 2230 to 2359 as night?